# How to add popupcontainer edit in the gridcontrol devexpress

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I am developing an application in WPF using MVVM design pattern. So in one of my user controls I have a gridcontrol (devexpress). This gridcontrol is bound to a datatable in my viewmodel class . For example the columns of my datatable are begin date , end date ,value, comments. Now in the column of comments I want a pop up container to appear in my gridcontrol. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add the following to your xaml namespaces
 `xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"`

You can use the `GridColumn.EditSettings` to edit or view the cell within an editor as the following inside your `<dxg:GridControl>`

```
<dxg:GridControl.Columns >
      <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="begindate">
               <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxe:DateEditSettings/>
               </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
     </dxg:GridColumn>
      <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="enddate">
               <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxe:DateEditSettings/>
               </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
     </dxg:GridColumn>
     <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="value"/>
     <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="comment">
               <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxe:MemoEditSettings/>
               </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
     </dxg:GridColumn>
</dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

And on a side note use a an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

**U**:to have a custom control for a column use a `DataTemplate`

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="fieldname">
   <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <youcontrolnamespace:someCustomControl x:Name="PART_Editor"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

**U**: for your last comment use  `dxe:PopupBaseEditSettings` with a `ControlTemplate`

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="fieldname">
      <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
              <dxe:PopupBaseEditSettings>
                   <dxe:PopupBaseEditSettings.PopupContentTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                                  <!--Your Controls to popup here-->
                        </ControlTemplate>
                   </dxe:PopupBaseEditSettings.PopupContentTemplate>
              </dxe:PopupBaseEditSettings>
         </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I get the editor , but is it possible to add custom controls in that editor as well?

Comment: @user3821877 sure, you need to use a DataTemplate for that

Comment: alright the data template makes sense. I have not implemented a custom control , currently am adding it to the xaml directly. So basically I want to wrap all the controls in a pop up container and wpf does not seem to have one. My data template currently consists of a grid with two rows and two columns. A label in row =0 col = 0 , textbox in row=0 , col = 1 and so on. But this causes the entire grid to be displayed in the gridcontrol cell. Is there some kind of a pop up control which will include the entire grid?

Comment: This solution works however when I try to fire events declared in the control template the method is not found.

Comment: you can't hook up events directly in control templates, the easist way is to name that control that you want to hook up with PART_something and handle the ContentRendered event in your view and use it to hook up an event handler to the control in the ContentTemplate, to find that control you call Template.FindName("PART_something", Controltype) and use += to hook the event handler to it

Comment: Alright, thanks I got how to do that. But there is one more problem when I add a control template to the GridColumn.EditSettings. The datatable bound to my gridcontrol does not reflect the binding in the UI. Basically without the control template the gridcontrol gets populated, however when I add the control templates the grid control no longer gets populated from the data table in the view model class. Would you know why that happens?

Comment: @user3821877 this should help you https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q517136 and on a side note, you should start using `ObservableCollection<T>` rather than a `DataTable` and follow the concepts of MVVM, they will make your life easier.